# How to concatenate a variable in ionic ngStyle?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm trying to create a quiz app just for fun.

But I can't change the background dynamically.
So basically, for each question, I have 5 answers (a,b,c,d,e).

If I choose the right answer, set the card background to green.
If I choose the wrong answer, set the card background to red and set the background of the correct answer to green.

> .html

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let answer of question.answers" tappable (click)="chooseAnswer(answer)" [ngStyle]="answer.is_correct ? correct : 'color'+answer.option">
    <ion-card-content class="card__content">
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="2" style="padding: 0;">
                <div class="option__wrapper">
                    <p class="answer__option">{{answer.option}}</p>
                </div>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col size="10" style="padding: 0; margin: auto;">
                <p style="text-align: left; margin: 0;" [innerHTML]="answer.description"></p>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

> .ts

```
chooseAnswer(answer) {
    //wrong answer
    if (!answer.is_correct) {
        switch (answer.option) {
            case "A":
                this.colorA  = {
                    'background':  'red',
                }
                break;
            case "B":
                this.colorB  = {
                    'background':  'red',
                }
                break;
            case "C":
                this.colorC  = {
                    'background':  'red',
                }
                break;
            case "D":
                this.colorD  = {
                    'background':  'red',
                }
                break;
            case "E":
                this.colorE  = {
                    'background':  'red',
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    // set the correct background as green
    this.correct = {
        'background':  '#00e676',
    }
}
```

But when I can't concatenate a variable on ngStyle:

> [ngStyle]="answer.is_correct ? correct : 'color'+answer.option"

When I run this, I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'colorA'

So the problem is here I guess: 'color'+answer.option".

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple version of your app on stackblitz to desmonstrate what you trying to accomplish (code is in pages/home folder):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/quiz-ionic-bztlxs

I set the answer "selected" to true when you click on the card:

```
  chooseAnswer(answer) {
    answer.selected = true;    
  }
```

I call getColor(answer) on ngStyle and use the selected attribute to define what color will be returned:

```
getColor(answer) {
    if (answer.selected)
        return { 'background-color': answer.isCorrect ? 'green' : 'red' };
    else
        return;
}
```

This is my card loop:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let answer of question.answers" tappable (click)="chooseAnswer(answer)" [ngStyle]="getColor(answer)">
    <ion-card-content class="card__content">
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="2" style="padding: 0;">
                <div class="option__wrapper">
                    <p class="answer__option">{{answer.option}}</p>
                </div>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col size="10" style="padding: 0; margin: auto;">
                <p style="text-align: left; margin: 0;" [innerHTML]="answer.description"></p>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Edit: I just realized I forgot about the green selection, but I'm sure you got how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass a string to [ngStyle], pass an Object and it will work:

In your case you can write a function that return the color object like this.

[ngStyle]=" answer.is_correct ? correct : getColor()"

```
getColor(){

 // in this method , you have to write the logic to return the color object
}
```

if you want to use string , you can use ngClass directive

Comment: Oh thanks! but how change the color in html from typescript?

Comment: You just have to return the object with the color, something like
rightColor = {
    color: 'blue'
  };
  
return rightColor;

Comment: @Edival but I want to be red just the selected wrong answer. If I do this, all the wrong answers become red

Comment: I posted an answer below with a suggestion.